# Upgrade paypal extension in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

i want to upgrade `only PayPal module` in magento is it possible to upgrade only PayPal module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple 
You have to install the below extension

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-payment-fee-3194.html
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more information as to how this extension would work. Thank you.

Comment: @David : you can find the appropriate information on https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/na/merchantlineup/home.page#mainTab=checkoutlineup&subTab=newlineup

Comment: I don't see how this answer is relevant for the question.